# How can I return custom error JSONs in place of the default ones provided by Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

*To make it a complete MRE, just create a basic Boot project with a web starter, Lombok and include the classes below. In my project, I use Spring Boot 2.6.4, but I believe it doesn't matter for the purpose of this question*

If you don't include any custom exception logic in your web application and make a request to a non-existent endpoint, you'll get a JSON similar to this one (assuming the request's headers don't include `Accept: text/html`, in that case you'll get a white-label html page):

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2024-02-09T05:02:23.763+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/bogus-path"
}
```

It's not bad, but what if I want to have more control (and I don't mean tweaking the JSON slightly with properties like `server.error.include-stacktrace`)?

To have my own exception handling logic, I wrote my own simple `ErrorController`:

```java
import com.example.helloworldmre.data.FailureMessage;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public FailureMessage error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new FailureMessage(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

@Getter
public class FailureMessage extends Message {
    @JsonProperty("request_path")
    private final String requestPath;
    private final HttpMethod method;
    public FailureMessage(HttpMethod method, String requestPath) {
        super("Could not perform the request");
        this.method = method;
        this.requestPath = requestPath;
    }
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public abstract class Message {
    private final String message;

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

My intent was to have it return responses like this one every time something bad happens (such as a request to an endpoint that doesn't exist):

```json
{
  "message": "Could not perform the request",
  "method": "POST",
  "request_path": "/some-bogus-path"
}
```

Instead, it always returns this response:

```json
{
  "message": "Could not perform the request",
  "method": "GET",
  "request_path": "/error"
}
```

In other words, I capture the path and the method of the redirect, not the original request

[This Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) suggested writing your own `HandlerExceptionResolver`

```java
@Component
public class RestResponseStatusExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      Object handler, 
      Exception ex) {
        return null; // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

But the breakpoint was never hit and the response was the same default JSONs from Boot

I also tried this:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public FailureMessage error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new FailureMessage(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

Again, the same default JSON. I guess, Boot doesn't throw any exceptions when receiving requests to non-existent endpoints so the handler doesn't kick in

In summary, how do I handle exceptions myself, returning custom JSONs, in a way that involves access:

1. To the *original* request path
2. To the *original* request method
3. To information what exactly went wrong (what exception was thrown or what HTTP status that exception was mapped to by Boot)

Comment: @xerx593 to reproduce, you may simply hit any nonexistent endpoint. In a bare-bones Spring Boot web project, there are pretty much no endpoints so it should be easy

Comment: @xerx593 in that project, I use Spring Boot 2.6.4, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* retrieve the original path, but you need to call `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI)` instead (which is equivalent to `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")`, it's a magic constant). Here's a corrected version of your `ErrorController`:

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.FailureMessage;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ResponseEntity<FailureMessage> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = getStatusCode(request);
        FailureMessage failureMessage = FailureMessage.builder()
                .errorDescription(getErrorDescription(statusCode))
                .method(getMethod(request))
                .requestPath(getRequestPath(request))
                .build();
        return ResponseEntity.status(statusCode).body(failureMessage);
    }

    private Integer getStatusCode(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (Integer) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
    }

    private String getErrorDescription(Integer statusCode) {
        String reasonPhrase = HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode).getReasonPhrase();
        return MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}", statusCode, reasonPhrase);
    }

    private HttpMethod getMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod());
    }

    private String getRequestPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.data;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
public class FailureMessage extends Message {
    private final String errorDescription;
    private final HttpMethod method;
    @JsonProperty("request_path")
    private final String requestPath;
    private final LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    private FailureMessage(Builder builder) {
        super("Could not perform the request");
        this.errorDescription = builder.getErrorDescription();
        this.method = builder.getMethod();
        this.requestPath = builder.getRequestPath();
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Getter
    public static class Builder {
        private String errorDescription;
        private HttpMethod method;
        private String requestPath;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder errorDescription(String errorDescription) {
            this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder method(HttpMethod method) {
            this.method = method;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder requestPath(String requestPath) {
            this.requestPath = requestPath;
            return this;
        }

        public FailureMessage build() {
            return new FailureMessage(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a response JSON. Keep in mind `ObjectMappper` doesn't guarantee any order of properties so here they don't precisely match the one of the fields

```json
{
  "message": "Could not perform the request",
  "errorDescription": "404 Not Found",
  "method": "GET",
  "timestamp": "2024-02-09T11:18:45.8504633",
  "request_path": "/bogus-path"
}
```

Alternatively, you can extend `DefaultErrorAttributes` (or directly implement `ErrorAttributes`) and compile your own map of attributes like so:

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.config;

import org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.DefaultErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(
            WebRequest webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes =
          new LinkedHashMap<>();

        addError(errorAttributes, webRequest);
        addMethod(errorAttributes, webRequest);
        addPath(errorAttributes, webRequest);
        addTimestamp(errorAttributes, webRequest);

        return errorAttributes;
    }

    private void addError(Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, WebRequest webRequest) {
        Optional<Integer> optionalStatus = Optional.ofNullable(
                (Integer) webRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST)
        );
        String errorDescription;

        if (optionalStatus.isPresent()) {
            Integer statusCode = optionalStatus.get();
            String reasonPhrase = HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode).getReasonPhrase();
            errorDescription = MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}", statusCode, reasonPhrase);
        } else errorDescription = "Unknown";

        errorAttributes.put("error", errorDescription);
    }

    private void addMethod(Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, WebRequest webRequest) {
        errorAttributes.put("method", ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getHttpMethod());
    }

    private void addPath(Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, WebRequest webRequest) {
        Object path = webRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        errorAttributes.put("path", path);
    }

    private void addTimestamp(Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, WebRequest webRequest) {
        errorAttributes.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

This way, Boot will still engage his own `BasicErrorController`, but it will use your `ErrorAttributes`

Result:

```json
{
  "error": "404 Not Found",
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/bogus-path",
  "timestamp": "2024-02-09T10:09:31.1491971"
}
```